# Firebase get auth info Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have an application that uses firebase auth to save the login information, and I would like to know how I can obtain this type of information such as the image url or displayName, with the uid of this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually create a `users` collection that will store information about the user. It is common practise to name these documents by the firestore uid so you can easily refer to these documents later after user authentication.